# Can i move to Europe as an ios developer from Pakistan?

Tags: software-industry, software-development, europe, pakistan

I am a 25 year old pakistani with education upto Intermediate which is equivalent to A levels. I am currently working as an iOS developer for 1.5 years. Is it possible for me to get a job anywhere in Europe with this education? My goal is to get to any good European country and escape Pakistan. If this question is not suitable for this platform please guide me to the right one.

Comment: This might not be the ideal place to ask since most can give very general suggestions at best. I think you could get some very solid advice from fellow Pakistani developers that managed to make the change. Maybe you know some in your life, maybe you can manage to find some on Linkedin and ask for advice in DMs - people who have gone through the same struggles can be very empathetic to your journey because they wish they had someone just letting them know how to do it.

Comment: VTC: The best answer to questions like this can radically change as markets and political situations change.  Thus making them very hard to give good answers that will not suddenly become very bad advice to someone else looking at them years from now.

Comment: What are "**A levels**" ? Is it like high school education level ? or college ? Bachelor ? Master ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible for me to get a job anywhere in Europe with this education?

Yes, many people migrated successful from Pakistan to Europe by getting jobs that offer visas. Mind that competition is stiff, as many people have the same idea as you do, and only that many companies are willing to go through the bother of obtaining a working visa. So you may want to figure out something that makes you stand out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible. But with only A-level education and limited experience, I think it is unlikely that a company will sponsor your visa; that's a lot of additional work for them, and you are competing against *many* candidates with better skills.

This would be easier if you had higher education or more experience or, ideally, both. Or if you managed to relocate at your own expense and then applied for jobs. Or both.

Answer (score 0):

For the legal/administrative part of the question, go to [Expatriates SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Regarding the workplace part of the question, companies in Europe hire local staff, they outsource work [offshore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offshoring) (often *not* hiring the workers, just contracting for specific work), and often they outsource work within Europe to countries with lower wages ([nearshoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outsourcing#Nearshoring)). So you would be competing with programmers who remain in Pakistan and work from there (with a much lower cost of living).

To get a [Blue Card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Card_(European_Union)) work visa in the EU, you need more work experience and a job offer which pays more than the average salary in that country.

If you do not think that you must emigrate/escape right now, look for jobs in companies which do outsourcing for European clients. It will give you an idea of what these clients are looking for. It will also give you the chance to build professional contacts and a reputation.